# Custom INDEX function that can handle greater than 255 Characters

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, transpose, type-mismatch

I am trying to use the `Application.Index` function with an variant 2D Array which contains some elements having >255 characters of text. This results in Variant/Integer Type `Type Mismatch` error. I am also unable to use `Application.Transpose` because of hitting this >255 characters limit.

Has anyone made any `Custom INDEX UDFunction` that can handle >255 characters of text to overcome this limit?

e.g. 
[image: Type Mismatch Error]

The snippet code looks like this:

```
........
........
For j = 1 to NoOfSlides
    A = (j - 1) * (nRw * 2) + 1
    B = IIf(A >= UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 1), (A + (nRw * 2)) - 1)
    If B > UBound(Arr, 1) Then B = UBound(Arr, 1)
    ab_Rng = Evaluate("row(" & A & ":" & B & ")")
    TmpArr(j) = Application.Index(Arr, ab_Rng, Array(1, 2))  ' Type Mismatch Error
    With oPres
        Set oSlide = .slides("Slide0_ABC").Duplicate
        oSlide.moveto toPos:=.slides.Count
        With oSlide
        ....
        End With

        If getDimensions(TmpArr(j))<2 Then 
            TmpArr(j) = Application.Transpose(TransposeDim(TmpArr(j)) )    ' Error
        End If
        For y = LBound(TmpArr(j), 1) To UBound(TmpArr(j), 1)
        .....
        Next y
    End With
Next j
........
........

Function getDimensions(var As Variant) As Long
    On Error GoTo Err

    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp As Long

    i = 0
    Do While True
        i = i + 1
        tmp = UBound(var, i)
    Loop

Err:
    getDimensions = i - 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear

End Function


Function TransposeDim(v As Variant) As Variant
' Convert 1D Array to 2D Array (1 -Based)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, Xupper As Long, Yupper As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    on error resume next
    Xupper = UBound(v, 2)
    if err.number <>0 then
        Redim Preserve v(1 to ubound(v), 1 to 1)
       Xupper = UBound(v, 2)   
    endif
    on error goto 0

    Yupper = UBound(v, 1)

    ReDim tempArray(1 To Xupper, 1 To Yupper)
    For x = 1 To Xupper
        For y = 1 To Yupper
            tempArray(x, y) = v(y, x)
        Next y
    Next x

    TransposeDim = tempArray
End Function
```

**Edit:**
Here is a [Sample.xlsm file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14rTKm-25uWT1ZNm013iwzk8lf4hxINEJmvZzCRgxUp8) and a [Sample PPT Template](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1szYmwAo7eHyEDLq6u3tEcWFK5iFKdJaH4Q6EV6Z6lO8) for anyone's perusal.

Comment: Is index a row,column argument, where you're passing an array?

Comment: The Application.Index function is expecting an integer for arguments 2 and 3, not a string or variant. This is where the type mismatch is coming from rather than passing a string >255 characters. https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/ whereas if you are looking for the string within the array then an Index/Match function should probably be used instead

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sorry i did not understand what you meant. Do you mean, whether i am passing 1 dimension or 2 dimensions of the array? I am just passing the array created from an Excel Range containing the data.

Comment: You are passing an array into the argument that is for the column.

Comment: Yes, it works with most ranges where the text in certain cells in <=255. If it exceeds this limit, i get the Type Mismatch error. So i am sure it has to do with the >255 Character limit being hit.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, i have shared a sample excel and ppt template for your perusal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, though strange enough, i found that as the `Arr` is defined as a Variant and pulls in Range data .e.g.

```
Arr = Sheet1.Range("A3:B8").Formula    ' a Variant/Variant array
```

`INDEX`, `TRANSPOSE`, `MATCH` etc., will not work and result in `Type MisMatch Error` on hitting the >255 Characters limit. I think it internally uses an `Integer index` and therefore maintains a 255 character limit.

However, if i defined the Array `Arr` as a `String`:

```
' Define Arr as a String
ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 1), 1 To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 2)) As String

For x = LBound(VarRng.Formula, 1) To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 1)
     For y = LBound(VarRng.Formula, 2) To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 2)
        Arr(x, y) = CStr(VarRng.Formula(x, y))
    Next y
Next x
```

'...then `INDEX`, `TRANSPOSE`, `MATCH` etc., will work properly, even though there are >255 Characters in the Array.

```
' Define Arr as a String
ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 1), 1 To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 2)) As String

For x = LBound(VarRng.Formula, 1) To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 1)
     For y = LBound(VarRng.Formula, 2) To UBound(VarRng.Formula, 2)
        Arr(x, y) = CStr(VarRng.Formula(x, y))
    Next y
Next x
`Arr` is now a Variant/String
'....
'....
For j = 1 to NoOfSlides
    A = (j - 1) * (nRw * 2) + 1
    B = IIf(A >= UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 1), (A + (nRw * 2)) - 1)
    If B > UBound(Arr, 1) Then B = UBound(Arr, 1)
    ab_Rng = Evaluate("row(" & A & ":" & B & ")")

    TmpArr(j) = Application.Index(Arr, ab_Rng, Array(1, 2))
'....
Next j
```

[Sample.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dNPyGOzXDsKhjKKUvFJXOU4AShLuvfCvjC6Q0OQ_4_w) and [PPT Sample Template.pptx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1szYmwAo7eHyEDLq6u3tEcWFK5iFKdJaH4Q6EV6Z6lO8)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String
Dim o As String

a(1, 2) = "testing " & String(255, "x")

o = Application.Index(a, 1, 2)

Debug.Print Len(o)
```

To support my comment, you are not using `index` correctly.  I think you'll need to use your `Array(1, 2)(0)` and `Array(1, 2)(1)`

Comment: It still doesnt work for me. I am splitting an Array created from a range of rows into set of <=10 rows each to dump into slide tables.If the text in the 2nd column of the range exceeds 255 characters, the code gives the `Type Mismatch error`. Otherwise works fine. Do you want me to share a sample workbook and ppt template for your perusal?